# How can I get a shape with a emission node to be brighter in the center?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, lighting

How to achieve similar effect with cycles in Blender - I mean stronger emission I middle and little darker on edges? I've tried to work with gradient nod but without success...

[image: expected effect]

Comment: You need it for text object or something simpler? It's quite easy to make it for circle or square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your text "Bar"
2. Duplicate it
3. Extrude both text meshes
4. Make one skinny and one fat
5. Change the offset of the "skinny" one to a negative number and place it inside the "fat" one.
6. Add a emission shader to the "skinny" text. Set it to 3 or so.
7. On the "Fat" text add a translucent shader.
8. (optional add another material to the extruded part like the picture.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I used glass BSB instead with roughnes of 8 and IOR of 5 (in my subjective opinion looked better) anyway this is result [link](https://goo.gl/photos/msBWDRqvuSkPMQ9j9)